# Python Input 0 automatically

Tags: python, input, equals, zero, enter

I have a variable equal to a input. I want to make the `input` function (when user presses <kbd>Enter</kbd>) to count it as `0`.

This is my code:

```
n1 = input('Εισάγετε Λεφτά :')
n2 = input('Εισάγετε Πλυσίματα Μέσα - Έξω :')
n3 = input('Εισάγετε Πλυσίματα Μηχανών :')
n4 = input('Εισάγετε Πλυσίματα Εξωτερικά :')
n5 = input('Εισάγετε Τι Ποσό Πήρε ο Σπύρος :')
n6 = input('Εισάγετε Έλλειμμα :')
n7 = input('Εισαγετε Πρόσθετο  Ποσό :')
n8 = input('Εισάγετε Ψιλά :')
answer = (str(float(n1) + float(n5) - int(n2) * 10 - int(n3) * 8 - int(n4) * 7 + float(n6) -     float(n7) - float(n8)))
print (float(answer))
input('Press Enter To Exit')
```

Currently, when I just press <kbd>Enter</kbd> on any of the inputs, it returns the `ValueError` because it needs a float.

Comment: You can test for an empty string `''` with e.g. `if not n1:` then use whatever default you like.

Comment: Just as a hint: you don't need to convert your answer to `str` and then to `float` again (especially for printing!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
n1 = raw_input('Εισάγετε Λεφτά :') or 0
n2 = raw_input('Εισάγετε Πλυσίματα Μέσα - Έξω :') or 0
n3 = raw_input('Εισάγετε Πλυσίματα Μηχανών :') or 0
n4 = raw_input('Εισάγετε Πλυσίματα Εξωτερικά :') or 0
n5 = raw_input('Εισάγετε Τι Ποσό Πήρε ο Σπύρος :') or 0
n6 = raw_input('Εισάγετε Έλλειμμα :') or 0
n7 = raw_input('Εισαγετε Πρόσθετο  Ποσό :') or 0
n8 = raw_input('Εισάγετε Ψιλά :') or 0
answer = (str(float(n1) + float(n5) - int(n2) * 10 - int(n3) * 8 - int(n4) * 7 + float(n6) - float(n7) - float(n8)))
print (float(answer))
input('Press Enter To Exit')
```

and this is in case you use python2. If you are running on python3 you can use input inplace of raw_input (as it is in your script)

[What's the difference between raw_input() and input() in python3.x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4915361/whats-the-difference-between-raw-input-and-input-in-python3-x)